# How to configure Exchange to forward mail to backup SMTP server via IP

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

In the company we are using an unix server for emails at the moment.

We are switching over to Microsoft Exchange Server.

How can I configure it to send a copy of each message posted into my inbox to a the backup SMTP server at a specific IP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transport rule in Exchange to do this.  Old question from a user that hasn't been here in 2 years so not going into it step by step, but assuming it was Exchange 2010 at this point (probably 07 then):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/01/28/3409250.aspx

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set up a remote domain for your linux box in exchange (eg linuxmail.yourdomain.com) with the IP of the linux box the smart host.

In properties -> Delivery options for your mailbox in exchange forward to the required address @linuxmail.yourdomain.com (you will need to create a mail contact with this address) and check "deliver message to both".

Comment: The first part of your answer is incorrect. Doing that would be configuring Exchange to send email destined for that remote domain to the server listed as the smarthost for that domain. It does not make Exchange send a copy of every email received in the OP's Inbox to that remote domain. The second part of your answer is the correct way to do it, but the OP needs to set up a Contact to forward a copy of the email to.